# ssis moving data between sql and access databases

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

In SQL Server Data Tools 2015, I would like to move data from a SQL Server 2012 database into a new access database(2005) and need to create the access table as part of the process.  Can this be done all in one Execute SQL process under control flow.  This will be part of a loop to run through a list of tables that need to be dynamically created and loaded into an empty access db.

I have created a connection manager and that is in the connection field for the access database and put the code into the SQL statement field under the general tab of the `Execute SQL Task` component.
Both databases are on my local machine.

```
"SELECT  a.* into providers from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  'SELECT * FROM newResults.dbo.providers') as a"
```

I get the following error:

> SSIS package "C:\Users\chris\source\repos\Integration Services
>   Project5\Integration Services Project5\Package1.dtsx" starting. Error:
>   0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task 2, Execute SQL Task: Executing the
>   query "SELECT  a.* into providers from OPENQUERYSET('SQLN..." failed
>   with the following error: "Syntax error in FROM clause.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly. Task failed: Execute SQL Task 2 SSIS package
>   "C:\Users\chris\source\repos\Integration Services Project5\Integration
>   Services Project5\Package1.dtsx" finished: Success.

Comment: Do you anticipate the tables to be changing as this package runs over time or is this a one-time effort to export data into Access?

Comment: the subset of tables will change, meaning we will have 30 tables in total but which of those will change with each run and we won't know which of those we will get, also over time some of the columns may change, thus the select * into...

Comment: Ok, so you run today and it populates providers. Tonight a column changes/is updated. Tomorrow you run and ...what? It blows up because the table already exists? It will always target a new Access database? Something else?

Comment: for each set of data, this is a multi step, one time etl process that goes from a large set of data and funnels down to a standard set through multiple transformation steps  before being loaded into their individual database.   So each time we do this it is reset, so it will be loaded into a empty database with no tables.  I am trying to standardize by dynamically grabbing a list of tables and moving them between sql and access, creating the tables  and columns as part of the process.  It all gets reset each time we process a batch of data.  So yes we target a new access database each time.

Comment: So the "provider" table will become a variable so I can put this step into a loop and process a batch of tables.  But I am trying to get this SQL Statement within the Execute SQL Task to work on one table before changing to a variable.   I believe I dont have this setup quite right, so still working through the right connections and syntax to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL contained in the Execute SQL Task is executed in the destination's context. The SELECT INTO FROM OPENQUERYSET statement is being passed to Access. Access doesn't have the OPENQUERYSET function and even if it did, your source is SQL Server, which Access doesn't know about unless you have made a connection to SQL Server in Access. Copy your SQL statement into Access and try to execute it and you'll see the same or a similar error. That's what the Execute SQL Task is doing.

Dynamic data is one of the more challenging problems in SSIS. The COZYROC tools include a lot of support for handling dynamic scenarios. Check out the videos for their [Data Flow Task Plus](https://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/data-flow-task) for some ideas.